# how to set a static table view for a TableViewController that is created with xib user interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I have created a controller class which extends UITableViewController and "with XIB user interface" option. XCode created 3 files, .h file, .m file and a .xib file. When I open the xib file, it has table view, but I am not able to set the table view content as "static cells" like we are doing in a table view that is there in the story board. Can you please guide me here to how to create a static table view that is created through a table view controller class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that in the Interface Builder when creating a NIB file for the classes. If you want you can include it in a storyboard and set the cells as static there however. If you wish to create it in a Separate NIB file though, you must use the classes that have been generated. These classes will already have all the functions that you will use. If you wish to set 5 rows in the table, each with a city name in them, you'd use the following functions:

```
@property(nonatomic) NSArray* cities;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        cities = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alacante",@"Bournmouth",@"London",@"Manchester",@"Tyme", nil];
    }
    return self;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel setText:[cities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are saying that you created a controller class which extends UITableViewController. When you extend UITableViewController in your class then you don't need to add table view from object library(appears bottom left corner). Xcode set all the basic requirements for adding tableview and it also set your delegate and datasource method and also implement required delegate method

In this case you to have only add your data(name text, detail text) to table view via programming

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement the `UITableView` `delegate` and `datasource` methods. Return your static values in the `-numberOfSections` and `-numberOfRowsInSection:` methods and return the cells according to indexPath in the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.